# How to get a random data in promela

Tags: promela, spin

I have met a question that "If babble1 is 1 then thebabbled frame is generated randomly with a sequence number between 0 to 255."So i need to define a inline functino to get a random data.Should I include a rand.h in C to Spin?Or there is another solution?

Comment: If you don't need to guarantee that the random number is picked with uniform distribution, you can use [select](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/select.html)

Comment: when i try to pick a random number between one to two hundreds,the rusult number seems to be always less than ten.

Comment: As I mentioned, the function does not guarantee a uniform distribution when simulating the model. However, when verifying the model, spin will check the whole state space if necessary. That is normally good enough for verification purposes. How do you intend to use this model?